# Python3 replace part of file name of all files and directory name in a directory

Tags: python-3.x

I have 4 files (with different extensions) in a directory as shown below.

```
Test1234_`enter code here`Dir (Directory)
 FileA_1234_test.dat
 FileAAB_1234_test.log
 FileABCD_1234_test.dbm
 FileABCDE_1234_test.jdt

I want to replace part of directory and file names as shown below
 Test6789_Dir (Directory)
  FileA_6789_test.dat
  FileAAB_6789_test.log
  FileABCD_6789_test.dbm
  FileABCDE_6789_test.jdt
```

How can we achieve this in Python3? I have no idea to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to do.
maybe something like this

```
def replace_names(path, str_to_replace='1234', replacement='6789'):
    import os
    for filename in os.listdir(first_path):
        if '_'+str_to_replace+'_' in filename:
            new_filename = filename.replace(str_to_replace, replacement)
            os.rename(filename, new_filename )
    os.rename(path, .replace(str_to_replace, replacement))
#now, run it...
replace_names('Test1234_Dir')
```